# Wordpress error trying to login via wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I made a website in Wordpress and used a free hosting service because we were two guys working on it. Now my client has finally bought the domain and the hosting and forwarded me the account information.

So I created the database, imported the other one (changed the URLs and stuff), uploaded the files. The website works perfectly but when I try to access the wp-admin area, it prompts me for the username and password and after I hit enter it hits me with this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rrozc21/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpass.php:483) in /home/rrozc21/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1315
```

I get this error 4 times on lines: 1315, 1317, 1319 and 1343.

I have no PHP knowledge and don't know how to fix this. I'm a web designer, not a programmer.

Comment: See what output is coming from class-phpass.php. Perhaps you've accidentally added whitespace characters before the `<php`, or maybe it is itself raising a notice/warning/error that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @user3477950: I agree with your question edit, but please keep edit remarks respectful.

Comment: (Aside to Chriss: you can always reschedule a meeting if your work is not ready to show. Or, you can demonstrate it but explain there's a technical problem with the hosting that you will fix as a priority. It _may_ be a problem with the hosting the client has supplied, which is why many designers also resell their own hosting that is guaranteed to work).

Answer (score 0):

You just check:

1. The problem is likely caused by a plugin (since pluggable.php is involved). Try deactivating them one by one at a time.
2. or may you have gotten some text or whitespace (spaces, newline) before the opening PHP tag or after the closing PHP tag in your theme's functions.php file. There can't be a single character before or after those tags.

may this help....